# Best Practice when returning data from an endpoint?

Tags: json, asynchronous

My colleague and I are building endpoints from scratch.  Our convention so far has been to "tag" data payloads like this:

```
  users: {[...]}
  customers: {[...]}
```

But what about the case when an individual `user` or `customer` is requested.  Should they be tagged something like this:

```
  user: {...}
  customer: {...}
```

Or is it common convention to just return the object in such cases?

Comment: Just return the object or the list. No point in tagging. It only wastes bandwidth and the requester should know what they requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't format all endpoint responses to return the same structure.  The caller should know what format to expect, so making your endpoints concise and reusable is more important than making all the payloads have similar structure.

It's most common to implement CRUD endpoints, which will return single records/an array of records of single data types. I'm not sure why in your case you would want to return both users and customers from the same endpoint, but that seems like a very specific, non-reusable endpoint.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining things better, Jacob.  `users` and `customers` are from separate endpoints, as are calls to get a specific `user` or `customer`.

I do appreciate your feedback though!